# Alternative of Math.random in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Math.random() function to get an integer from range of 0 to 'max' number.
But According to sonarqube, it is "Security Hotspots" medium issue.

```
private getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
```

Comment: related, possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036514/make-sure-that-using-this-pseudorandom-number-generator-is-safe-here

Comment: In node.js, you can use the crypto module, for example `crypto.randomInt`: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html In the browser, you can use `window.crypto.getRandomValues`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues

Comment: Is this *expected* to have secure random number generation? Because one possible solution is to completely ignore the SonarQube warning and disable it, if it doesn't make sense. There are plenty of times you may want just some sort of random data without necessarily that being security related. But if you use it to generate session IDs or something, then you *do* need better pRNG.

Answer (score 0):

```
const cryp = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;
var tab= new Uint32Array(1);
cryp.getRandomValues(tab);
```